# Multiple jQuery - Plupload doesn't work when second jQuery library added

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

im trying to implement plupload into an existing template but am running into issues when adding the plupload JQuery file the existing template stops working like drop down menus and other features

this is the current head tags without the plupload files

```
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' />
<title>$capital_name</title>
<link href='bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />

<!-- jQuery UI -->
<!--<link href='plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='plugins/jquery-ui/jquery.ui.1.10.2.ie.css'/>
<![endif]-->
<link href='assets/css/main.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link href='assets/css/plugins.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link href='assets/css/responsive.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link href='assets/css/icons.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' href='assets/css/fontawesome/font-awesome.min.css'>
<!--[if IE 7]>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='assets/css/fontawesome/font-awesome-ie7.min.css'>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
    <link href='assets/css/ie8.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<![endif]-->
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<script type='text/javascript' src='assets/js/libs/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js'></script> 
<script type='text/javascript' src='bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='assets/js/libs/lodash.compat.min.js'></script>
<!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src='assets/js/libs/html5shiv.js'></script>
<![endif]-->
<script type='text/javascript' src='plugins/touchpunch/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='plugins/event.swipe/jquery.event.move.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='plugins/event.swipe/jquery.event.swipe.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='assets/js/libs/breakpoints.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='plugins/respond/respond.min.js'></script> <!-- Polyfill for min/max-width CSS3 Media Queries (only for IE8) -->
<script type='text/javascript' src='plugins/cookie/jquery.cookie.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='plugins/slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='plugins/slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.horizontal.min.js'></script>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='plugins/flot/excanvas.min.js'></script>
<![endif]-->
<script type='text/javascript' src='plugins/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='plugins/flot/jquery.flot.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='plugins/flot/jquery.flot.tooltip.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='plugins/flot/jquery.flot.resize.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='plugins/flot/jquery.flot.time.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='plugins/flot/jquery.flot.growraf.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='plugins/easy-pie-chart/jquery.easy-pie-chart.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='plugins/daterangepicker/moment.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='plugins/blockui/jquery.blockUI.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='plugins/noty/jquery.noty.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='plugins/noty/layouts/top.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='plugins/noty/themes/default.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='plugins/uniform/jquery.uniform.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='plugins/select2/select2.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='assets/js/app.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='assets/js/plugins.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='assets/js/plugins.form-components.js'></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    'use strict';

    App.init(); // Init layout and core plugins
    Plugins.init(); // Init all plugins
    FormComponents.init(); // Init all form-specific plugins
});
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='assets/js/custom.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='assets/js/demo/pages_calendar.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='assets/js/demo/charts/chart_filled_blue.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='assets/js/demo/charts/chart_simple.js'></script>
```

the below is the lines im trying to add when i run into problems and the template stops working

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='assets/plupload/jquery.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='assets/plupload/plupload.full.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='assets/plupload/jquery.plupload.queue.min.js'></script>
<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='assets/plupload/jquery.plupload.queue.css' media='screen'>
```

any help is very much appreciated im stuck currently and cannot work out how to proceed

code added thanks to below

```html
 <script src='assets/plupload/jquery.js'></script>
<script>
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('button').click(function(){
        jQuery('p').text('jQuery is still working!');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: i think same class name for different function should be there, so didn't work as expected.

Comment: where abouts would i start looking ?

Comment: u have separate jquery for scroll, swipe, daterangepicker and etc.., actually bootstrap blugin may support for all ur needs

Comment: any chance of an example of what to change

Comment: console is empty not reporting anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **jQuery** `noConflict()` Method. The `noConflict()` method releases the hold on the `$` identifier, so that other scripts can use it.

In the below code we are using `noConflict()` just after including `jquery` js file, we are releasing `$` which is a global function for jQuery to be used by others and we are using `jQuery` as an alias instead of `$`.

You can have your custom variable declared as an alias when using noConflict() like `var jq = $.noConflict();`. Now you can access using `jquery` using `jq` alias.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("button").click(function(){
        jQuery("p").text("jQuery is still working!");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>The noConflict() method releases the hold on the $ shortcut identifier, so that other scripts can use it.</p> 

</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:**

User jQuery `noconflict` after this in your code not after plupload js.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='assets/js/libs/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'></script>
<script>
$.noConflict();
</script>
```

**Note:** Now if you have written any jquery code in your application which is referencing `jquery-1.10.2.min.js`, replace `$` by `jQuery`.

Comment: this seems to half work it allows both JQuery files to load now however the file upload button on plupload doesnt work just links straight back to there site and when removing the above code it allows to select files

Comment: Make sure you are using jQuery alias properly. jquery file post which you have using noConflict. To reference that jquery file you have to use jquery as your alias. For other it will be there default one which I suppose is $.

Comment: sorry im complete new to JQuery and have no idea how to do that i have updated the code above to show my edits to the code if it helps the jquery file im using for the plupload is jQuery JavaScript Library v1.11.1

Comment: have completed the above however now im missing half of the drop down menus

Comment: it's very hard to tell you without seeing the entire code. Dependencies on jquery are conflicting. One solution might be check out if plupload is supported on the jquery version you are using i.e jquery-1.10.2.min.js or is there any version of plupload available that suppor 1.10.2 so that you can remove jquery.js

Comment: what files would you need access to?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89651/discussion-between-akki619-and-nathan).

Answer (score 0):

This is b'se plupload uses the old 1.9.0 jquery. I solved this by putting all pupload code above the tag that calls the later jQuery version then added a

```
<script>
$.noConflict();
</script>
```

after the jQuery.

e.g.

```
...
<script type='text/javascript' src='assets/plupload/jquery.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='assets/plupload/plupload.full.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='assets/plupload/jquery.plupload.queue.min.js'></script>
<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='assets/plupload/jquery.plupload.queue.css' media='screen'>
...
<script type='text/javascript' src='assets/js/libs/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'></script>
<script>
$.noConflict();
</script>
...
```